# ¿Por que me aparece ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS?

Tags: php, python, sql, backend

Estaba trabajando con una web  que estoy haciendo tiene una especie de login y me apareció este error las redirecciones las hago con header.
Esta página no funciona
La página mivhost.com te ha redirigido demasiadas veces.
Borrar las cookies.
**ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['input-login'])) {
    if ($_COOKIE['contraE']<3) {
            $usuario=$_POST['input-usuario_txt'];
            $password=$_POST['input-password_txt'];
            $verifica=new Verificador();
            $cantidadVacios=$verifica->hayVacios($usuario,$password);
            if ($cantidadVacios>0) {
                echo "<div class=\"div-mensajeSuscripcion\">";
                echo "<p class=\"texto-error\">Los datos de los campos no deben estar vacios</p>";
                echo '</div>';
            }
            else {
                $consulta=new Consulta('administradores');
                $resultado=$consulta->loginEncriptado($usuario,$password);
                if($resultado>0){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
                    header('location:edicion.php');
                }else {
                    echo "<div class=\"div-mensajeSuscripcion\">";
                    echo "<p class=\"texto-error\">Tu usuario o contraseña son invalidas</p>";
                    if(isset($_COOKIE['contraE']))
                    {setcookie('contraE',$_COOKIE['contraE']+1,time()+604800);}
                    else{setcookie('contraE',1,time()+604800);}
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                $consulta->cerrarConsulta();
            }
    } else {
    echo "<div class=\"div-mensajeSuscripcion\">";
        if ($_POST['input-password_txt']=='perdonmeequivoque') {
        echo '<p class="texto-error">estamos reiniciando tu clave para que puedas volver intentarlo</p>';
        setcookie('contraE',1,time()-1);
        }else {
            echo '<p class="texto-error">Ya has tenido hecho muchos intentos</p>';
        }
    echo '</div>';
    }    
} else {
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        header('location:edicion.php');
    }
}
```

Solo es php pero puse python porque pienso que el error no es del codigo php antes me funcionaba ahora esque no me funciona

**muchas gracias por intentar  ayudarme**

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda que compartieras el código implicado. De lo contrario, todo serán conjeturas.

Comment: además de lo que ya te comentaron, se mas preciso, pues veo etiquetas de distintos lenguajes, ocupas todos esos a la vez? de no ser así deja solo aquel que se refiera a tu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a todos ya resolví el problema me di cuenta que era porque estaba haciendo una redirección infinita desde mi web sin querer
**Este error por lo general se debe a redirecciones sin parar de una web a otra**

Answer (score 3):

Aunque ciertamente puede ser el código y la sugerencia de fedorqui es mejor que la tengas en cuenta, a mi me ha sucedido eso en un par de ocasiones.

Una de las veces fue por que estaba activo el mod_security de apache, y una de las reglas no me permitía hacer llamada de un mismo script al mismo script varias veces, según eso puede ser una brecha de seguridad y me toca revisar cómo organizar eso.  El problema puede estar en el mod_security, puedes probar a desactivarlo y ver que pasa, pero no es lo recomendable, si es eso, es mejor saber por qué está molestando.

Pero la situación más común que he tenido en ese tipo de casos, es que si el servidor tiene cpanel, nunca he logrado que funcione correctamente las opciones que trae el mismo cpanel, que ayudan a redireccionar el http al https, sólo lo logré una vez y traté de replicar en los otros servidores, sin resultado favorable alguno, entonces tocó a la antigua, desactivar la función de redirección desde cpanel, y hacerlo con un archivo .htaccess desde el directorio público del sitio web.

---

Aunque puede ser algo del navegador, lo único que veo en el código, que está redirigiendo es

```
header('location: edicion.php')
```

Que para estar seguros es mejor poner "Location", con L, aunque leí que la especificación dice que no es necesario y no he encontrado nada sobre navegadores sesinbles al "case" (mayúsculas o minúsculas).

Lo otro es que es cierto lo que dicen en los comentarios, pero voy más por la parte de, que tiene que ver python? Sólo veo código en php.

Y lo otro, será que hay algo mal en el código del archivo edicion.php, que hace que se devuelva al archivo de login?

Comment: deberías esperar a que el OP siga la recomendación de agregar el código, de otra manera solo estamos asumiendo y no tenemos base para asegurar ninguna respuesta pues ni siquiera es claro en el lenguaje que usa, por que coloca php y python además sql

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta la leí después de haber dado con el error